# Hadasim: Righteous or not?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, sefer-vayikra

The Midrash ([Vayikra Rabba 30:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.30.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says Hadasim refer to Jews who have good deeds but lack Torah:

וַעֲנַף עֵץ עָבֹת, אֵלּוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל, מָה הֲדַס יֵשׁ בּוֹ רֵיחַ וְאֵין בּוֹ טַעַם, כָּךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל יֵשׁ בָּהֶם שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהֶם מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים וְאֵין בָּהֶם תּוֹרָה

yet the Gemara ([Sanhedrin 93a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.93a.5?lang=bi&with=Ben%20Yehoyada&lang2=en)) says Hadasim refer to the righteous:

> כיון שנסתכל בחנניה מישאל ועזריה נתקררה דעתו שנאמר (זכריה א, ח) והוא
> עומד בין ההדסים אשר במצולה ואין הדסים אלא צדיקים שנאמר (אסתר ב, ז)
> ויהי אומן את הדסה - Once He looked at Hananiah, Mishael, and Azariah He was placated, as
> it is stated: “And he stood among the myrtle bushes [hadassim] that
> were in the depths [bametzula].” And hadassim is referring to no one
> but the righteous, as it is stated: “And he raised Hadassah, that is
> Esther, his uncle’s daughter” (Esther 2:7). Hadassah is an appellation
> for the righteous Esther.

How do we reconcile these two definitions of Hadasim according to Chazal?

Comment: Are Jews who have good deeds not righteous?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point, though the Midrash seems to be contrasting 4 different levels, the highest being esrog - מָה אֶתְרוֹג זֶה יֵשׁ בּוֹ טַעַם וְיֵשׁ בּוֹ רֵיחַ, כָּךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל יֵשׁ בָּהֶם בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהֶם תּוֹרָה וְיֵשׁ בָּהֶם מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים - which I would think refers to the righteous. It's also hard to be righteous if וְאֵין בָּהֶם תּוֹרָה

Comment: You can be a tzadik to some degree as an am haaretz